# Regex for directory and file listing in C

Tags: c, regex, linux

I'm trying to write an expression that would filter out several types of directories and files when listing the contents of a directory. Namely, I want to avoid listing the current directory (.), upper directory (..), hidden files and other more specific directories.

This is what I have now:

`[\\.+]|cgi-bin|recycle_bin`

However, it doesn't match `.`, `..`, recycle_bin nor `cgi-bin`. If I remove all the `|` operands and leave the expression to only  `[\\.+]`, it works (matches `.`, `..`, etc). Which is strange, because I'm pretty sure `|` = OR. Do I miss something?

UPDATE 1: Here is the code I use:

```
            regex_t regex;
            int reti;
            char msgbuf[100];

            /* Compile regular expression */
            reti = regcomp(&regex, "[\\.+]|cgi-bin|recycle_bin", 0);


            if( reti )
            { 
                fprintf(stderr, "Could not compile regex\n");
                exit(1);
            }

            reti = regexec(&regex, entry->d_name, 0, NULL, 0);
            if( !reti ){

                printf("directoy %s found -> %s", path, entry->d_name);
                printf("\n");

            }
            else if( reti == REG_NOMATCH ){

                //if the directory is not filtered out, we add it to the watch list
                printf("good dir %s", entry->d_name);                    
                printf("\n");

            }
            else{
                regerror(reti, &regex, msgbuf, sizeof(msgbuf));
                fprintf(stderr, "Regex match failed: %s\n", msgbuf);
            }
```

Comment: How are you using this regular expression? Can you post the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use ["extended REs"](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_04). With [regular ("obsolete") ones](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03), the `|` is an ordinary character.

```
regcomp(..., REG_EXTENDED);
```

Also see the [`regcomp()` description](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/regcomp.html).

Comment: Thanks. I knew it should be a easy one. I even read something about the REG_EXTENDED option, but in a hurry and missed the whole point. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Fllow the pmg's comment and try this regex:

```
^([.]{0,2}|cgi-bin|recycle_bin)$
```

`[.]{0,2}` it match `.` and `..`

Answer (score 0):

This isn't what the C regex library is for. Its purpose is to let you build programs which accept regexen as input. This problem is solved much better without regex:

```
#define SIZE(x) (sizeof (x)/sizeof(*(x)))
char *unwanted[] = {
     ".",
     "cgi-bin",
     "recycle_bin",
};
int x;
for(x=0; x<SIZE(unwanted); x++)
     if(strstr(entry->d_name, unwanted[x])!=NULL)
           goto BadDir;
//good dir
BadDir:
```

Ignoring what your present regex means, you probably want something like:

```
char *begins[] = {".", "private_"};
char *equals[] = {"recycle_bin", "cgi-bin"};
char *contains[] = {"_reject_"};

for(x=0; x<SIZE(begins); x++)
    if(strncmp(entry->d_name, begins[x], strlen(begins[x]))==0)
          goto BadDir;
for(x=0; x<SIZE(equals); x++)
    if(strcmp(entry->d_name, equals[x])==0)
          goto BadDir;
for(x=0; x<SIZE(contains); x++)
    if(strstr(entry->d_name, contains[x])!=NULL)
          goto BadDir;
//good dir...
BadDir:
```

Comment: First of all, your code doesn't do the same thing that my regex does Dave ;). Take a closer look. Then, what if I want to match all the directories that start with, let's say, "private_". Lastly, I don't think the performance is an issue, there is probably a difference between the two, I didn't benchmark, but I think is not huge.

Comment: Aah, I saw the `"^...$"` in other answers, and assumed. Nevertheless, using the regex library isn't the right thing to do in c. Perl? Sure.

Comment: @ValentinRadu P.S. Now, it does

Comment: No it doesn't :) I let you spot the difference! Otherwise, I don't think I agree with you regarding "isn't the right thing to do in c". Is there a particular reason for which you think so?

Comment: Actually, it does;  look closely at your regex, and see why. Also, that's why it's not the right thing in C.

Comment: Had a better look and it does. Sorry for not being focused. In any case, I could easily modify the regex to match only the strings that *start* with one, two or N `.` characters and end in `.png` `.jpg` *or* `jpeg`. How much code would you write to do that? Plus, imagine how easy I could change the rule, you would have to write code again. I'm not going to argue about this. Thanks for your opinion, but I don't agree.