# Wildcard not expanded in recursive cp using execvp()

Tags: c, linux, fork, ipc, execvp

Though there are multiple files under path "/home/abhijit/Documents/LINUX/editor/" , but I am not getting desired output in "temp" (which should copied all files from editor folder) folder instead output is coming error as : **"cp: cannot stat ‘/home/abhijit/Documents/LINUX/editor/*’: No such file or directory"**.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main( void )
{
    char* argv1[10] = { "cp", "-rf", "/home/abhijit/Documents/LINUX/editor/*", "/home/abhijit/Documents/LINUX/temp", 0 };
    execvp( argv1[0], argv1 );
}
```

But if i say as below , it works fine.

```
 char* argv1[MAX_ARGS] = { "cp", "-rf", "/home/abhijit/Documents/LINUX/editor/", "/home/abhijit/Documents/LINUX/temp", 0 };
```

Comment: If you need shell-globbing, you can use `system()` instead

Comment: Also see [How to use execvp()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27541910/608639), [Directory listing with wildcards in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38972164/608639) and [Regex for directory and file listing in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10464646/608639).

Comment: @BhargavRao - I attempted to vote to undelete Abhijit's answer but I cannot due to your status. Please forgive me for challenging your decision, but I think Abhijit's answer should stand. It has the complete code available, and it credits's SomeProgrammerDude's answer. I think its better than SomeProgrammerDude answer because SPD's answer lacks the code.

Comment: I strongly believe stack-overflow gives complete information as much as possible. BhargavRao - I am completely agree with you.The code which i have provided is the "SIMPLE USAGE of execvp() and glob()" to resolve the issue and complete credit of the ans goes to SomeProgrammerDude's inputs. As per SomeProgrammerDude's point fork and exec should be used , which i am not denying it. By the way i already made that comment.
As per my opinion the code which i have provided "should not be deleted" as it convey the basic functionality of the same to achieve output. Please correct me if i am wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The asterisk pattern `*` is expanded by the *shell* and not by the `cp` command itself.

You could make it work if you run the `cp` command through a shell, either by invoking a shell with the `-c` option through `exec` or by using the [`system`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html) function instead of `exec`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Yes , through shell it's working fine as expected.
But ,Sorry i am using busybox without shell. But how to achieve in execvp() system call itself?Is there any possibility to achieve it?

Comment: @AbhijitSahu If you want to use [*globbing*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)) wildcards, you either have to use a shell, or use the [`glob`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/glob.3.html) function and multiple `cp` commands (one for each match).

Comment: Thank you very much for the inputs - "Some programmer dude".
I have updated the code at answer comment. Thank you again for the help.

Comment: @AbhijitSahu You do know what the [`exec`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html) functions *do*? That they *replace* your program with the one you try to `exec`? The `exec` function only return on error. Perhaps you should also learn about [`fork`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) and [the fork-exec idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork%E2%80%93exec).

Comment: Yes , i know it very well. Thanks for the clarifications! Actually i am using fork() , sigchld_hdl handler with  execvp() in my code-base. Instead of writing fork() with whole long prog here i had raised the questions with simple  execvp() example - just to convey this wild character issue. Thanks.